# How to make full-screened MacOSX bundle killable?

Tags: macos, bundle, glfw

Exposition:

I am writing an GLFW app on MacOSX. The app is a Mac bundle.

I want my app to run in fullscreen mode (easy, use GLFW_FULLSCREEN). Problem is .. my code is still buggy, and I do not know how to kill a full-screened app that infinite loops (i.e. if the exit(0); is not called in the program; I don't know how to force kill it).

Question is: how can I set up a MacOSX Glfw Bundle so taht I can force-kill it when it infinite loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up expose so it triggers on a screen corner, and leave Activity Monitor running in the background.  When you want to kill the app, expose across to Activity Monitor and kill it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not at my Mac right now, but from memory either Command+Option+Escape or Command+Option+Shift+Escape will kill a fullscreen app like a game that isn't responing.

If that doesn't work, try enabling spaces. Many apps that capture all keystrokes won't/can't take over the Control+Arrow Key shortcut to change to another space.

Final option: setup a spare computer; an old PowerBook or Compact Mac or something like that is ideal, and SSH into the dev machine and kill the offending process(es).